# JS - Elements still null after body.onload

Tags: javascript, dom, onload

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494620/when-does-a-body-onload-gets-called), by the time the body onload gets called, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

I have some JS that is supposed to fire at body onload but my attempts to `getElementByID` are returning `null` which makes me think it's firing earlier than I think it is.

**Am I wrong in my interpretation of `body.onload` or am I doing something else wrong?**

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.document.body.onload = doStuff;

    function doStuff() {
        var txtElement = document.getElementById("myTextField");

        if (txtElement != null) {
            alert(txtElement.value);
        }
        else {
            alert("Element not found!"); //This alert is always thrown
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please add the HTML as well so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Per your edit, you're doing something else wrong. but what *something* is can't be determined given the code in the question. We need to know how the target element is being created.

Comment: Your edit invalidates an answer.

Comment: @KevinB - I guess I'm not 100% sure. I'm using a form building module for DNN that is generating the form fields for me. I'm not sure when or how the plugin does it but I'm beginning to think my issue is there.

Comment: Sounds like it very well could be. anything that adds elements after the fact isn't going to be ready before the onload handler occurs. you'd have to hook into whatever is creating said elements. It sounds like you should probably be using DNN to do whatever it is you're trying to do rather than custom js.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually calling the `doStuff` function before the DOM is loaded because you have parenthesis after the function name, which causes the function to be invoked as soon as that line is encountered.

When you register a function as a callback to an event, you just want to reference the function, not invoke it. Also, you only need to register the "page" `load` function to the `window`.

Change:

```
window.document.body.onload = doStuff();
```

to:

```
window.onload = doStuff;
```

---

Additionally, you should modernize your code and, instead of using an event property of an element (which only allows for one function to be stored as a callback to an event), you should use the **[`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** method to register callback functions.

Lastly, the `type` attribute is no longer necessary on `script` tags.

```
<script> 
    window.addEventListener("load", doStuff);

    function doStuff() {
        var txtElement = document.getElementById("myTextField");

        if (txtElement != null) {
            alert(txtElement.value);
        }
        else {
            alert("Element not found!"); //This alert is always thrown
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That didn't solve my problem. Apparently it's a duplicate question, though, so I'll go check that out. Hopefully the answer is there.

Comment: @TheIronCheek Trust me. This is a problem. You may have others as well, but this IS an issue that would cause exactly what you are indicating is happening.

Comment: @TheIronCheek the duplicate just suggests the same solution as this answer. If this doesn't solve the problem, then you haven't adequately described it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - I updated the code per your recommendation. The problem still exists which leads me to think the element isn't being generated until after load. I'm using a form builder plugin for DNN so I have no idea when and how the elements are created.

Comment: @TheIronCheek As I initially requested in the comments, you should show us all the relevant code so we can help you.